# Query with Campaign Member status

Tags: query, list

[image]

I am trying to query with `CampaignMemberStatus` object and getting this error:

> Illegal assignment from List CampaignMemberStatus> to
>   List CampaignMemberStatus>

Query:

```
List <CampaignMemberStatus> lst=new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();
lst=[SELECT CampaignID,label FROM CampaignMemberStatus];
```

Comment: if possible provide screenshot pf error you are getting.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma I have added screenshot

Comment: @devsfdc check  is there any apex class created with name `CampaignMemberStatus` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the code in Developer console and its working fine. The error might be because of below reason

- If there is any apex class with the same name of the standard or global sObjects while creating List, map,set the above error will reflect.

We can solve this problem in two ways:

1. We have to rename our Apex Class to some other name.
2. Use 'Schema' before sObject while creating List, Set, Map (Don't use 'schema' before sObject in SOQL Query)

Comment: Yes...That'works!

Answer (score 1):

```
List<CampaignMemberStatus> lst=new List<CampaignMemberStatus>();
 lst=[SELECT CampaignID,label FROM CampaignMemberStatus];
```

I test this code and it is working perfectly. test it

Comment: Same here, tested in Developer console and works fine !

Comment: tested again.continue to get the error.Is there any setting or anything that i might be missing.